# Morse theory and homology of an algebraic surface (example)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry

Let $T_n$ denote the $n$-th [*Chebyshev polynomial*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomial) and define $$f_n(x,y,z):=T_n(x)+T_n(y)+T_n(z)\;\;\;\text{ and}$$ $$Z_n:=\mathcal{Z}(f_n) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3,$$
the [*Banchoff-Chmutov surface*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChmutovSurface.html), where in general, $\mathcal{Z}(f_1,\ldots,f_k)$ denotes the zero set of polynomials $f_1,\ldots,f_k$, i.e. $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3; f_1(x,y,z)=\ldots=f_k(x,y,z)=0\}$.

Let us prove, that this is a surface. By the implicit function theorem, it suffices to prove that the points, where $[D_x{f_n},D_y{f_n},D_z{f_n}]$ is zero, do not lie in $Z_n$ (here $D_x$ is just the partial derivative). This is quivalent to showing that the set $$\mathcal{Z}(f_n,D_xf_n,D_yf_n,D_zf_n)=\mathcal{Z}(T_n(x) + T_n(y) + T_n(z),D_xT_n(x),D_yT_n(y),D_zT_n(z))$$ is empty. This can be done by using (from wiki page) $D_xT_n(x) = nU_{n-1}(x)$ and Pell's equation $T_n(x)^2 - (x^2 - 1)U_{n-1}(x)^2 = 1$, to obtain $\mathcal{Z}(1 + 1 + 1) = \emptyset$.

Let us observe the height function $Z_n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $(x,y,z) \mapsto ax + by + cz = [a,b,c][x,y,z]^t$. It is linear, so its derivative is $[a,b,c] :T_pZ_n \rightarrow T_p\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}$. Its critical points are therefore those, where the tangent plane $T_pZ_n$ has normal $[a,b,c]$. But the tangent plane of $\mathcal{Z}(f)$ always has normal $[D_xf,D_yf,D_zf]$. Thus the critical points of our height function are those $x,y,z$ where $[D_xf_n,D_yf_n,D_zf_n]=[a,b,c]$, i.e. the critical points are $$\mathcal{Z}(f_n,T_n(x) - a,T_n(y) - b,T_n(z) - c).$$ Now I don't know how to check if these critical points are nondegenerate. I don't even have local parametrizations to work with.

**Question:** Can one calculate the homology $H_\ast(Z_n)$ by using the elementary methods from Morse theory (i.e. structural theorem, handle decomposition, Morse inequalities, Morse complex)?

Comment: Check out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46212/interesting-implicit-surfaces-in-mathbbr3 for lots of cool pictures and code to generate these.

Comment: Shouldn't the formula be $[Dxf_n,D_yf_n,D_zf_n]=[a,b,c]$ up to multiplication by a constant? Also, $D_xf_n=nU_{n-1}(x)$, not $T_n(x)$, so the big equation is wrong. Finding a set of local coordinates should not be hard: Assuming without loss of generality that $c\neq 0$, then $x$ and $y$ will form a set of local coordinates. If you can find these critical points and check that they are nondegenerate and such, the only difficulty in computing the homology will be the compactness of the surface. If I understand correctly it will be compact for $n$ even and not for $n$ odd. 

Comment: @Igor WOW! WOW!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The  function $h(x,y,z)=z$, corresponding to $a=b=0$ will do the trick. Assume $n$ is even.   Using a bit of Morse theory I will show that

$$ \chi(Z_n)= \frac{n^2(3-n)}{2}. \tag{1} $$

A point $(x,y,z)$ on $Z_n$ is critical for $h$ iff

$$  T'_n(x)= T_n'(y)=0, \;\; T_n(z)=-T_n(x)-T_n(y) $$

Now the critical points  of $T_n$ are all located in the interval $[-1,1]$ and can be  easily determined from the defining equality

$$ T_n( \cos t) = \cos nt, \;\;t\in [0,\pi], \tag{A} $$

so that

$$ T_n'(\cos t) = n\frac{\sin nt}{\sin t} $$

This  nails the critical points  of $T_n$ to

$$x_k = \cos \frac{k\pi}{n},\;\; k=1,\dotsc, n-1.$$

Note that

$$ T_n(x_k)= \cos k\pi=(-1)^k $$

so that the critical points of $h$ on the surface $Z_n$  are

$$\bigl\lbrace (x_j,x_k,z);\;\; T_n(z)+(-1)^j+(-1)^k=0,\;\;j,k=1,\dotsc, n-1 \bigr\rbrace.  $$

Now we need to count the solutions of the equations

$$T_n(x)=0,\;\pm 2. $$

The equation $T_n(x)=0$ has $n$ solutions, all situated  in $[-1,1]$.

On the interval $[-1,1]$  we deduce from  (A) that $|T_n|\leq 1$.  The polynomial $T_n$ is even and is increasing on $[1,\infty)$. We conclude that the equation $T_n(x)=-2$ has no solutions, while the equality $T_n(x)=2$ has two solutions.   Thus the critical set of $h$  splits  into three parts

$$ C_0= \lbrace (x_j,x_k,z);\;\;j+k\in 2\mathbb{Z}+1,\;\;T_n(z)=0\rbrace, $$

$$ C_2^+= \lbrace (x_j,x_k,z);\;\;j,k\in 2\mathbb{Z}+1,\;\;T_n(z)=2, z>1\rbrace, $$

$$ C_2^-= \lbrace (x_j,x_k,z);\;\;j,k\in 2\mathbb{Z}+1,\;\;T_n(z)=2, z<-1\rbrace. $$

From the above discussion we deduce  that the points in $C_2^-$ are minima and the points in $C_2^+$ are maxima. The function $h$ is a *Morse* function and  the saddle points are exactly the points in $C_0$;  for a proof, [click here.](http://liviusmathblog.blogspot.com/2012/08/on-banchoff-cmutov-surfaces.html)

Thus  the Euler characteristic of $Z_n$ is

$$ \chi(Z_n)={\rm card}\; C_2^+ +{\rm card}\; C_2^- -{\rm card}\; C_0. $$

Now  observe that

$$ {\rm card}\; C_2^\pm = \Bigl(\;{\rm card}\; [1,n-1]\cap (2\mathbb{Z}+1) \;\Bigr)^2= \frac{n^2}{4},$$

$$ {\rm card} \; C_0 = n\times \Bigl( \frac{n(n-2)}{4}+ \frac{n(n-2)}{4}\Bigr)= \frac{n^2(n-2)}{2}. $$

(To explain the above equality note that there are $n$ independent possible choices for $z$, the zeros of $T_n$.  Then we need to choose  integers $(j,k)$ in $[1,n-1]\times [1,n-1]$ so that exactly one of them is odd.   The number of  pairs $(j,k)$ with $j$ odd, $k$ even and $1\leq j,k\leq n-1$ is $\frac{n}{2}\times \frac{n-2}{2}$. We have an equal number of pairs $(j,k)$, $1\leq j,k\leq n-1$ with $j$ even and $k$ odd.)

We conclude  that the Euler characteristic of $Z_n$  is

$$\chi(Z_n)= \frac{n^2}{2}- \frac{n^2(n-2)}{2}=\frac{n^2(3-n)}{2}. $$

For $n=2$ we get that $Z_2$ is a sphere. This agrees  with  the pictures  on the site indicated by I. Rivin.

**Update.**  The above computations do not  explain whether $Z_n$ is connected or not.  To check that it suffices to look at the critical values  of the above  function corresponding to saddle points. These critical values are the zeros $\zeta_1<\dotsc <\zeta_n$ of $T_n$. The level zet

$$ Z_n\cap \lbrace z=\zeta_k\rbrace $$

is the algebraic curve

$$ T_n(x)+T_n(y)=0. \tag{C} $$

This forces $|x|,|y|\leq 1$ because $T_n(x)> 1$ for $|x|> 1$ and $|T_n(x)\leq 1$ for $|x|\leq 1$.  We can use the  *homeomorphism*

$$[0,\pi]\ni t\mapsto x=\cos t\in [-1,1] $$

to give an alternate description to (C).  It is  the singular curve  inside  the square $[0,\pi]\times [0,\pi]$ with coordinates $(s,t)$ described by

$$\cos ns+ \cos nt =0.$$

This can be easily visualized as the intersection of the square with the  grid

$$ s\pm t\in (2\mathbb{Z}+1)\frac{\pi}{n} $$

which is  connected. Now it is not very difficult to conclude using the Morse theoretic data on $h$ that $Z_n$ is connected.

**Update** To better explain my answer to Leon, below is a rendition of $Z_6$ where one can see three   layers, yellow, green and blue.

[image]

The equality  (1) predicts

$$\chi(Z_6)=\frac{6^2(3-6)}{2}=-54. $$

One can verify this directly as follows. Consider the   $1$-dimensional simplicial complex $C$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$  depicted below

[image]

The surface $Z_6$ is homeomorphic to the boundary of a thin tubular neighborhood $T$ of this set in $\mathbb{R}^3$. (Think of the edges as   thin spaghetti.) For this reason

$$ \chi(Z_6)= 2\chi(T)= 2\chi(C). $$

Let me   give an alternate proof of the equality

$$\chi(C)=-27. \tag{E} $$

The complex $C$ has $8$ Green vertices of degree $3$, $12$ Red vertices of  degree $4$, $6$ Blue vertices of degree $5$ and a unique  Black vertex of degree  $6$. Thus the number $V$ of vertices of this complex is

$$ V= 8+12+6+1=27. $$

The number $E$ of edges is half the sum of degrees of vertices. Thus

$$ E=\frac{1}{2}( 3\times 8 + 4\times 12 + 5\times 6+ 6\times 1)=\frac{1}{2} (24+48+30+6)=54. $$

Hence

$$\chi(C)= 27=54=-27.  $$

Comment: Hmm, judging from the pictures, if I'm not mistaken, for $n=2(k+1)$, we have a cube (sphere) with $k^2$ holes drilled in each direction $x,y,z$, so I would say that $Z_n$ has genus $k^2+k^2(k+1)+k^2(k+1)=k^2(2k+3)$, for$k\in\mathbb{N}$. For $n=2,4,6,8$, this gives genus $0,5,28,81$. Thus the Euler characteristic is $\chi=2-2g=2-2k^2(2k+3)$, i.e. for $n=2,4,6,8$, we get $2,-8,-54,-160$. But $n^2-\frac{n^3}{4}$ gives $2,0,-18,-64,-150$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The picture is more complicated than that.  For $n=2(k+1)$ there are $(k+1)$-layers the look like the top face of the cube.

Comment: Umm, $Z_4$ has just one hole drilled in each of the three directions, and hopefully, we agree that it has genus $5$, hence $\chi=-8$. However, $n^2-\frac{n^3}{4}\neq-8$ for $n=4$. Something must be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There is an errorin $C_0$.  The answer is $n^2(3-n)/2$.

Comment: If $n=4$ we obtain according to the corrected formula that $\chi(Z_4)= -8$ so  that the genus of $Z_4$ is $5$.


Comment: Yes, now it agrees with my intuition. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Liviu Nicolaescu: Regarding the connectivity of $Z_n$, why does it suffice to prove that the level set $Z_n\!\cap\!\{z\!=\!\zeta_i\}$ is connected for every $\zeta_i\!=\!h(\text{saddle point})$? For example, if we have a disjoint union of an upright torus and a sphere, and if the sphere is small enough that both saddle points of the torus are above the sphere and the bottom of the torus is below the bottom of the sphere, then both level surfaces of corresponding to saddle points are connected (they are the wedge of two circles), yet the surface is not connected. 

Comment: Furthermore, you claim that $Z_n\!\cap\!\{z\!=\!\zeta\}=\{T_n(x)\!+\!T_n(y)\!=\!0\}$, but don't we have $Z_n\!\cap\!\{z\!=\!\zeta\}=\{T_n(x)\!+\!T_n(y)\!=\!-T_n(\zeta)\}$?

Comment: @ Leon In the case at hand all the local minima/maxima are in fact **global**  minima/maxima. In your example you have  local minima which are not global minima. If $z=\zeta_k$ is a critical level  where saddle points are located, then $T_n(z)=T(\zeta_k)=0$ so that this critical level set  is decribed by $T_n(x)+T_n(y)=-T_n(z)=0$.

Comment: Yes, now I understand it. Thank you for your illustrative and elegant solution. It's somewhat surprising how nicely all calculations go through. I imagine that, given a different family of polynomials instead of $T_n$, we would have much more problems.

Comment: It would be interesting to see  if this works with other orthogonal polynomials which have many things in common with the Chebyshev polynomials.